# Start Rails application on Boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upstart, openproject

I have OpenProject, a Ruby on Rails application, I want to make it up with the system boot, made a script and call this script in Upstart, but when I see the log, the following message appears: **/usr/bin/env: ruby: File or directory not found**. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/openproject/openproject
bundle exec rails server -d >> ~/log
```

Comment: Is it a typo or did u miss a space after cd ?

Comment: Hello, time to copy that was wrong ... but is right in the script.

Comment: Looks like it the your path variable is not set properly. You can use .ruby-version in your rails project and i guess it should work and remove the statement bundle exec from your command. It should work, I guess

Comment: add export PATH="$PATH/home/openproject/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin"....but with the same error.

Comment: Are you using RVM (Ruby Version Manager) or something similar?

Comment: Max, how can I find out?